# SNMP v3 network source restriction?

Tags: snmp

Can't for the life of me figure out how to restrict an SNMP v3 user by source (e.g. limit access to the host via that user to a specific IP address or range). No matter what I try the user seems to allow access from anywhere, from any IP.

My `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`:

```
com2sec mynetwork  192.168.0.0/24    read_only_community_string
group   MyROGroup  usm               mynetwork
view    all        included  .1
access  MyROGroup  ""      any       noauth    exact  all    none   none
```

"`mynetwork`" SNMP v3 user was created via `net-snmp-create-v3-user` and it works (polling data via a Solarwinds server). However when I update the `snmpd.conf` file with a bogus IP (e.g. 254.254.254.254) - it still works. When I do a similar configuration with SNMP v2 and community strings - the restrictions work as expected.

Help! :)

P.S. If this makes it easier: what is the simplest possible SNMP v3 configuration restricting access to a specific IP range?

Comment: Any OS today has a firewall to use, and you can set up firewall rules to block packets for SNMP.

Comment: Indeed - but that wasn't the question. (1) Changing firewall rules in the enterprise is a way bigger deal vs. tightening application or service configuration. (2) If someone disables the firewall temporarily or by mistake, the service remains more secure. (3) Attack surface reduction must happen at every level especially application or service one.